# suggestion for probability and stats text to suit my learning style.

Tags: textbooks, general-pedagogy, self-learning, statistics, probability

I am of a mature aged learner and want to learn probability and statistics at a senior high school (k12) and undergraduate level for my own general understanding. I have discovered in the past that I learn best by having large well graduated problem sets where the variations between problems are small and obvious, rather than having relatively few problems with significant differences between them. Based on previous testing I can conclude that I am of moderately above average general intelligence but I am a slow learner. I can be patient. Most texts do not have enough problems and the steps from problem to problem are to great for me to learn efficiently. Can anyone suggest a good text book. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for making a clear and specific first question!

Comment: Schaum's Outline is usually a good bet and there is one for "probes and shafts".  Google also shows a 'humongous book of statistics'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My AP Statistics class uses [The Practice of Statistics (Josh Tabor)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1464108730). It has a large variety of exercises at the end of each chapter and they are definitely in the order of difficulty. They are also presented in the same order as the ideas are presented in the chapter itself. There are definitely both "practice" type questions and "deep thinking" type questions, and in my opinion the problems are "graduated." There are generally two very similar problems back-to-back, one even one odd, with only the odd ones having the answer in the back of the book.

Answer (score 1):

I use Neil Weiss, *Introductory Statistics* in my classes. It's my favorite textbook that I use.

[Introductory Statistics, 8th Edition at Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321393619)

Comment: Thank you, but it says the text "emphasizes statistical thinking over rote drill and practice," I take this to mean "as opposed to rote/practice." However I find that for me real understanding comes most easily from lots of (well structured) practice, not from limited practice. Is what I am asking antithetical to mathematical thinking itself, or am I just looking for a text book from another (bygone) era?

Comment: I am working through  https://www.probabilitycourse.com and it seems good but even more graduated careful exercises would be better.